# Выбрать последние 5 уникальных записей отсортированных по дате

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы:

> Payments c полями:

```
- Id 
- Productid
- Date
```

> Products c полями:

```
- Id
- Name
```

Как составить запрос, чтобы он возвращал 5 последних по дате проданных уникальных товаров. Например:

```
Payments.Id     Products.Name     Payments.Date
1               Шорты             01/01/2019
7               Штаны             01/01/2018
11              Рубашка           01/01/2017
15              Кофта             01/01/2019
19              Носки             01/01/2018
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT id, 
                     productid, 
                     date, 
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY productid 
                                        ORDER BY date DESC) rn
              FROM payments )
SELECT cte.id,
       p.name,
       cte.date
FROM cte, 
     products p
WHERE p.id = cte.productid
  AND rn = 1
ORDER BY cte.date DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: А можно как-то обойтись без хаки с номером строки?

Comment: @user2455111 Что значит "без хаки"? Window functions и CTE - штатные, установленные стандартом, возможности.

Comment: Но тут используется лишний столбец, я думал может быть как то можно через Order Max(Date) может быть?

Comment: @user2455111 Можно. Но зачем делать через задницу то, что можно сделать нормально?

Comment: Просто интересует, есть ли еще "нормальные" варианты помимо этого? Задача, просто много где может возникать, неужели это единственное правильное решение и в microsoft это не продумали, что приходиться пользоваться Window functions и CTE и выбирать первую строку отсортированную по дате?

Comment: @user2455111 Можно. Группируйте, сортируйте по MAX(date), берите 5 первых. Одно "но" - нечитабельно получится... *в microsoft это не продумали* Они-то тут каким боком? SQL стандарты совсем другие люди пишут. К тому же описанная задача - увы, не самая частая, чтобы под неё что-то особенное воротить.